# Accessing a file on my domain relative to port

Tags: html, node.js, port, url-routing

I am running a node server on port 3000. I have a css file stored just on `http://mydomain.com/style.css`but since every page right now is `http://mydomain.com:3000/randompage.html` How can I access the style.css file? I can get `http://mydomain.com:3000/styles.css` from the page I am working on, but that doesn't exist.

What is the best way to deal with this situation? I suppose it applies to any files I need to access.

Comment: I'm confused. Does that mean you have two HTTP servers running on the same server, one on port 80 and the other on 3000? Why is there suddenly a domain `owlfever.com`?

Comment: Ah that was a mistake about the domain. I fixed it

Comment: And yes I guess I have an apache server running as well as a node server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a simple solution using a relative URL or some HTML magic in the page.

The usual solution is to install a module in Apache or a function in node.js which will redirect some requests to the other server so that for your HTML, everything seems to be coming from a single source.

This document should get your started when using Apache: [Using mod_rewrite for Proxying](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html)